# "Select case" performance issue

Tags: sql, rdbms

I am facing performance issue in below mentioned SQL query :

```
select column1, 
   (SELECT CASE fl.ISDELETED WHEN 'T' THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END  FROM FILE fl
     WHERE lower(fl.FILE_TYPE) LIKE 'doc' AND fl.FILE_ID=doc.FILE_ID   ) AS alias1 ,
   (SELECT CASE fl.ISDELETED  WHEN 'T'  THEN 'T' ELSE 'F'  END FROM FILE fl
     WHERE lower(fl.FILE_TYPE) LIKE 'xls'   AND fl.FILE_ID=doc.FILE_ID ) AS alias2

FROM DOC doc
```

Is there any alternative(JOIN or any other option)  of select case statement so that it will take less time to execute? I am calling this query from java code

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Instead of java you should have tagged your rdbms

Comment: You're using a like query on a potentially large data-set. Also, I don't see why you can't just use an "OR" statement for your two file type clauses. I'd convert that column to something "definite" so you can use an equals with an OR statement. Far quicker

Comment: @JeffWatkins Thanks for the response but I am not getting your point. Can you please give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this with an explicit `join`:

```
select d.column1,
       (case when f.isdeleted = 'T' and lower(f.file_type) = 'doc' then 'T'
             when lower(f.file_type) = 'doc' then 'F'
        end) as alias1,
       (case when f.isdeleted = 'T' and lower(f.file_type) = 'xls' then 'T'
             when lower(f.file_type) = 'doc' then 'F'
        end) as alias2             
from doc d left join
     file f
     on f.file_id = d.file_id;
```

For performance, you want indexes on `file(file_id, file_type, isdeleted)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your FILE_TYPE to be a definite thing, rather than like i.e. migrate it all as a one-off update to be lower-case so you don't have to do conversions etc.

Remove the subselects and just use regular SQL

```
SELECT column1,
       f1.FILE_TYPE,
       CASE fl.ISDELETED WHEN 'T' THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END  
FROM 
       FILE fl
WHERE 
       (fl.FILE_TYPE = 'doc' OR fl.FILE_TYPE = 'xls') AND 
       fl.FILE_ID=doc.FILE_ID
```